# Style element within perspective

Tags: html, css

I would like to style elements in the `perspective` to be straight(3d) currently it's flat because of perspective. I am trying to achieve this kind of design. See how the alphabets and flag post image are lining up.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.container {
    perspective: 100px;
    perspective-origin: bottom;
    width: 63%;
    margin: auto;
}
.percpective {
 height: 500px;
 background-color:#9DDAE4;
 perspective: 100px;
 transform: rotateX(7deg);
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 35px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="percpective">
     <table>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>    
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: rotate the td in the opposite direction `transform: rotateX(-7deg);` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Temani commented giving opposite direction of `transform: rotateX(-7deg);` will solve the issue.

```
table td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 35px;
    font-size: 25px;
    transform: rotateX(-7deg);
}
```